# Is there a specific name for $Y=(X-c)^+$, as a function of a random variable?

Tags: probability, functions, notation, terminology, real-numbers

Let $X$ be a random variable, and for a given $c>0$ let $f_c:\mathbb R\to [0,\infty)$ be a measurable function defined by $x\mapsto \max\{x-c,0\}$. Write $Y:=f_c$.

I have not been able to find a name in the literature for this function. Note that
$$
Y=\begin{cases}
X-c,&c<X,\\
0,&c\geqslant X,
\end{cases}
$$
or more succinctly
$$
Y = (X-c)\cdot\mathsf 1_{(c,\infty)}(X).
$$

Having a definite name for this function would be very helpful.

Comment: We can call $Y$ "the positive part of $X-c$" I believe.

Comment: Your definition of $Y$ is incorrect. It should be $X-c$ if $c\lt X$ and $0$ if $c\geq X$ (or you can exchange the strict and non-strict inequality).

Comment: @Suzet I fixed the typo.

Comment: Indeed, that's just called the positive part (and indeed, as @ArturoMagidin pointed out, your second equation is incorrect). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_parts

Comment: Typo is still there.

Comment: This are sometimes called ["hinge functions"](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/py-earth/content.html).

Comment: @GEdgar I've rewritten the question so it is more clear (and correct).

Answer (score 1):

I think we call them as "HINGE FUNCTIONS".

Multivariate adaptive regression splines, implemented by the Earth class, is a flexible regression method that automatically searches for interactions and non-linear relationships. Earth models can be thought of as linear models in a higher dimensional basis space. Each term in an Earth model is a product of so called “hinge functions”. A hinge function is a function that’s equal to its argument where that argument is greater than zero and is zero everywhere else.

h(x−t) = [x−t]+ = {  x−t,x>t;   0,x≤t;